# button value undefined when passing

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass the value of my button to a function that just logs that value for now. The function is in a functions class that is imported in my welcome.ts file. 
**Welcome.html**

```
  <ion-content padding id="page1">
<h1 id="welcome-heading4" style="color:#000000;text-align:center;">
Question-CF
</h1>
<div class="spacer" style="width:320px;height:427px;" id="welcome-spacer1"></div>
<button  value='0' (click)=barrierClick(this.value)   id="welcome-button1" ion-button color="positive" block style="font-weight:500;border-radius:50px 50px 50px 50px;">
Begin
</button>
</ion-content>
```

**Welcome.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {functions} from '../functions';
import {BarriersQ1Page} from '../barriers-q1/barriers-q1';


@Component({
selector: 'page-welcome',
templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
})

export class WelcomePage {
nextPage = BarriersQ1Page;



barrierClick(val){

functions.barrierClick(val);
}




constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

}


}
```

**Functions.ts**

```
 export class functions
 {
 public static barrierClick(val: string)
 {
 console.log(val);

 }

 }
```

Currently, the console logs undefined and I want it to log the button value currently "0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `this` reference in the `html`. 
You can pass the entire `click` event to the function like,

```
(click) = barrierClick($event)
```

This will contain all the information including the value of the button.

And in your `ts` file,

```
barrierClick(event) {
   functions.barrierClick(event.target.value); // Should pass button's value to functions.barrierClick
}
```

Comment: It still gives me undefined when I use **event.target.value**, It worked when I changed it to **event.currentTarget.value**. thank you

Comment: Since the event handler is attached to the button and the event is triggered by the same button, the `target` should be same as `currentTarget`. I don't understand how did you get `undefined` with `target`.

Comment: I don't understand either, I am quite new to typescript.